# Is it possible to set multiple permission in hook_permission()?

Tags: 7, routes, users

Let's say I have a custom module. Now I upgrade the module and add some new functionality which is bound to the old functionality. I already have a hook_permission() set in the old version. But now need a second permission to keep unauthorised users away from accessing the new function. Is it possible to set a second permission in the same module? How would I do that?

That's how my hook_permission looks for now:

```
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'name of permission' => array(
      'title' => t('Access Something'),
      'description' => t('Access Something to do something'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course:

```
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'name of permission' => array(
      'title' => t('Access Something'),
      'description' => t('Access Something to do something'),
    ),
    'name of another permission' => array(
      'title' => t('Access Something Else'),
      'description' => t('Access Something Else to do something'),
    ),
  );
}
```